# How to customise form_for in Rails with different routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, form-for

### Problem domain

- We have `Projects` and `Milestones`
- Once created, a `Milestone` has a `Project`

### Routing

In my original approach, I had something like:

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :milestones
  end
```

So all the RESTful routes looked like: `projects/PROJ_ID/milestones/ID`

This was getting a bit long for my liking and you don't need the `Project ID` all the time: only just when you create the `Milestone`.

Now, the routes look like:

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :milestones, :only => [:new, :create]
  end

  resources :milestones, :except => [:new, :create]
```

When I create a new `Milestone` (first route):

- I use the nested resource
- This is so as to get the `Project ID`
- We are creating a new `Milestone`, we need a `Project ID`

With other `Milestone` operations (second route):

- I use standard `Milestone` resource
- We're already operating on an existing `Milestone`
- The `Milestone` already carries a `Project ID`

### Problem: Rendering __form.html.erb

All is fine, except when I get to the views for `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb` for `Milestone`. These render `_form.html.erb`.

**Original approach (all resources nested)**

```
<%= form_for([@project, @milestone]) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Due to nested resource, we need to have `Project` and `Milestone` as parameters.

The same code above works fine for `new` and `edit`. because the original approach assumed `Project/Milestone` nested routing for all REST operations.

**Current approach (only create/new nested)**

We want `_form.html.erb` to look like this when we are creating a new `Milestone`:

```
<%= form_for([@project, @milestone]) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

And for all other REST operations on a `Milestone`, we want `_form.html.erb` to look like this:

```
<%= form_for(@milestone) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

### So ...

Current solution is not pretty:

- View code checks if "new" or non-"new" action called it
- Use "if" test to choose which code (as above) the view should execute

It's not DRY, it's messy and it feels like there should be a more elegant way.

Would appreciate any input. Very much still coming up to speed with Rails. Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass variable with you resource to `_form` partial. For example:

New:

```
render "form", :resource => [@project, @milestone]
```

Edit:

```
render "form", :resource => @milestone
```

Inside the form

```
<%= form_for resource do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! If I am passing `:resource` with two variables (e.g. `@project`, `@milestone`), how do I differentiate between them within the `_form` partial?

Comment: Hm you doesn't need to differentiate them, just pass to form_for and it does all the work. Or you can try something ugly, for example `is_array(resource)`

Answer (score 2):

I would normally put the *contents* of the form in the partial, and write out the form_for in each file.

update:

```
<%= form_for @milestone do |f| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f} %>
  <%= f.submit "Update my object" %>
<% end %>
```

create:

```
<%= form_for [@project, @milestone] do |f| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f} %>
  <%= f.submit "Create Object" %>
<% end %>
```

as it's usually the form fields don't change, but button text, form ids, etc., etc. might be different. Also gives you flexibility to add additional fields, text., etc.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I think the other answer fit my needs a bit better, but I'd like to keep your approach on hand :)